# How to create server.properties inside IBM websphere application server on startup

Tags: java

I have to create a server.properties file inside WEB-INF/classes of Websphere Application ND server on sever startup.This code below works in my local websphere on windows but when deployed on cluster I am not seeing the file.Please help!!

code snippet:

```
public class RuntimePropertyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
    ServletContext context = contextEvent.getServletContext();
    OutputStream output = null;
    WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context);
    DynamicConfiguration dynamicConfiguration = (DynamicConfiguration) springContext.getBean("dynamicConfig");

    try {
        String sep = File.separator;
        String contextPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes");
        String propFilename = contextPath + sep + "server.properties";
        String hostname = null;
        File file = new File(propFilename);
        if(!file.exists()){
            InetAddress hostServerIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            if(hostServerIp != null){
                hostname = hostServerIp.getHostName();
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.setProperty("disable_lastrun", "true");
                prop.setProperty("mrc_servlet_reload", "false");
                prop.setProperty("mpower_server", dynamicConfiguration.getProperty("mpower_server"));
                output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                prop.store(output, null);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
    log.info("Context " + name + " Destroyed");
}
}
```